# Having Trouble with Minimal CD Installation

Tags: system-installation, 15.10

I just bought a new SSD for my self-built desktop with the intent of installing Ubuntu 15.10 onto it.  I have a laptop which already has Ubuntu 15.10 on it (installed using the minimal CD), but my desktop is much more powerful and there are a few things that I'd much rather do on it.

I originally built my PC with one SSD and a leftover hard drive.  I have Windows 10 residing there.  It was just recently that I added the additional SSD (a Samsung EVO 850).  As far as I can tell, the installation of the SSD went fine.  It shows up in my bios and the vendor string is correctly reported.  But this is aside from the problem (I think?) because I never actually get to the point of partitioning anything in the install process.

Every time I run the minimal installer, I get stuck on the "detecting hardware" step.  It stays at 0% forever.  I have no idea what piece of hardware is causing the problem, or whether or not this is a possible bug.

I'm using an ASUS M5A99FX PRO R2.0 with an AMD CPU.  My graphics card is an XFX Radeon 270x (obviously correctly detected since I can see the installer GUI).  I have a pcie wireless card, but given that the installer correctly finds it and lets me use it to download the release files, I don't think that's the problem.

The only thing that gives me a hint is when I was trying to install Mint when Ubuntu wasn't working.  Mint didn't seem to like one of my SATA connections, leading me to believe that one of the hard drives is causing the problem.  In response to this, I looked up a few solutions.  A number of people have had success with moving which SATA ports are used.  I tried moving them around, but nothing seems to work.

I should also mention that I've tried a non-minimal USB installer, but that doesn't even let me try Ubuntu.  It gets stuck on a black screen.  It's probably running into the same hardware issue as the minimal installer.